# Shell script to restart multiple services at a time

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Need to restart multiple services at a time using a shell script. we are now manually getting into each folder (as files for different services are in different paths) and re-starting them using a command.
eg:

`cd /opt/apps/service1 and run the command ./**** -start`

for service2:
go to folder `cd /opt/apps/service2`

and execute the command `./**** - start`

Comment: Iterate your requirement clearly with supporting data. Also, please share what you have coded so far.

Comment: Uhm, how about not reinventing the wheel and write systemd unit files, define the appropriate dependencies, enable them on system startup?

Answer (score 1):

This demo bash script should work for you

```
#!/bin/bash

services=(
    # path, restart cmd
    "/deploy/service1, ./svr1 restart"
    "/deploy/service2, ./super_svr -s"
    "/deploy/service3, python ./svr3 restart"
)


for ((i = 0; i < ${#services[@]}; i++))
do
    entry="${services[$i]}"
    path=`echo $entry | cut -d',' -f1`
    cmd=`echo $entry | cut -d',' -f2`
    pushd $path
    $cmd
    popd
done
```